# deployment errors on migration of jboss 5.1 to jboss 7.1.1 final

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I am getting following error, when i deployed my war in jboss 7.1.1, it was working fine in jboss5.1.

Below error is coming for almost all the jars (in web-inf/lib), how to resolve this, please help em on this. below mentioned is only for jar exception.

ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./usr/share/lib/jax-qname.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./usr/share/lib/jax-qname.jar".main: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \usr\share\lib\jax-qname.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

```
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \usr\share\lib\jax-qname.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

```
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97) [rt.jar:1.6.0_14]

at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:63) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Class-Path entry in a MANIFEST.MF somewhere in your application that points to /usr/share/lib/jax-qname.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt set any entry in MANIFEST.MF, and i didnt set anywhere this jar file.
My manifest.mf looks like.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_14-b08 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Title: TEST Application
Composite-Version: TEST_2_3_2
Implementation-Version: 2014-03-07 11:45:07